# aws ec2 describe-security-groups + awk sed

Tags: security, aws, amazon-ec2

I am sure this is not the most efficient method, but I need help formatting the results of this aws command:

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --group-ids sg-xxxxxxxxxxxxx --region=us-east-1 --profile=default | sed -n '/\"FromPort\"\: 22\,/,/\"ToPort\": 22\,/p'
```

The results show me data specific to port 22.  Example results are:

```
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "1.2.3.4/32"
                        },
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "5.6.7.8/32"
                        },
                        {
                            "Description": "test1",
                            "CidrIp": "4.3.2.1/32"
                        },
                        {
                            "Description": "test2",
                            "CidrIp": "8.7.6.5/32"
                        },
```

As we see, some entries may contain a description, others may not.

I would like to format the results like this:

```
1.2.3.4/32
5.6.7.8/32
4.3.2.1/32 <tab> test1
8.7.6.5/32 <tab> test2
```

I tried adding --filters to the aws command, but it's not clear to me how best to get the desired output.
Many thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: This looks like JSON, you should really use something like `jq` instead.

Comment: Would you be able to provide an example of how I can use jq in this case to get the desired results?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: It will depend on the actual JSON structure, but here's an example converting the output you have to valid JSON: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/nCwTzB4kmY/

Comment: Thanks for your help muru.   However, the command didn't work for me.
I get the following error:
``

Comment: Obviously it won't work. As I said, it depends on the actual JSON. You haven't shown us that.

Comment: Sorry, my last message was sent prematurely.

I get the following error:
`parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 4, column 0
`

The actual JSON was in my original message above.  Let me know what else I can provide.

Comment: You haven't shown the actual JSON. You have shown a cut up version. Provide the actual output of `aws` without your `sed` processing.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the AWS CLI, I'd recommend using the `--query` and/or `--filter` flag(s) to get the necessary formatting and output.

[AWS CLI provides both server-side and client side filtering](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/v1/userguide/cli-usage-filter.html).

The `--filter` flag provides server side filtering and also might help with HTTP response times if the dataset is large, however the `--query` flag offers more powerful client-side filtering, you can use [JMESPath syntax](http://jmespath.org/) for filtering with `--query` flag.

Here's an example using the `--query` flag to get desired output.

NOTE: There's quite a few ways that you can slice and dice this using a combination of `--query` + `--filter` or even `--query` alone.

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --group-ids sg-xxxxxxxxx --filter 'Name=ip-permission.from-port,Values=[22]' 'Name=ip-permission.to-port,Values=[22]' --query 'SecurityGroups[*].IpPermissions[?FromPort == `22` && ToPort == `22`].IpRanges[*].[CidrIp,Description]' --region <AWS_REGION> --profile <PROFILE> --output text
```

Each API method offers specific filters against which you can "search" within your response on the server side, so consult the documentation of API calls for that.

Also pay attention to the `--output text` used, which is what really outputs in the format that you are specifically looking for, though it's just a space and NOT a tab.

You'll notice I used the filters provided with the EC2 SG API (for e.g.  `ip-permission.to-port`).
Also, mind the backticks used in this command above , on my Mac it runs fine.